# SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error , SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'extend'

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, freemarker

I am working with servlets with freemarker templates, I am using jQuery for AJAX calls, here is my code:

```
function openCompareView(event) {
        var itemIds = getItemIdsToCompare();
        var imgs = getItemImagesToCompare();
        if (itemIds.length > 0) {
            var url = "../shop/quickview/compareview.jsp";
            var params = "cvids=" + itemIds + "&ims=" + imgs

            jQuery.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  data:params,
                  type:'POST',
                  dataType:'html',
                  context: document.body,
                  success: function(result){ 
                  console.log(result);
                 // jQuery('#compareview-container').html("  "+(result));
                  var div = document.createElement('div');
                  div.innerHTML = result;
                  var elements = div.childNodes;

                  window.document.getElementById('compareview-container').innerHTML=div.innerHTML;   
                  }
            })
        }
    }
```

Here is freemarker template:

```
<html>
<head>
<assign cdnUrl="http://abc.com"> 
<style>
#expressorder,#exproductid {
    margin: -100px;
}
</style>

<link href="/css/qv.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/qv-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/qv-ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/qv-ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/compare-view-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/compare-view.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%; float: left;">
<div class="compare-view_header">Comparison View
<!--    <div id="cv_main_img"> -->
<!--        <div id="cv_main_img_handle" style="height: 20px; padding-left:100px; float:right">-->
<!--            <img id="drag-handle" src="/images/4_direction.png"-->
<!--    style="position: relative; left: -10px; top: -5px; cursor: pointer;" width="24" /> -->
<!--        </div>-->
<!--    </div>-->
</div>

<!-- close button -->
<span id="close-it"> 

 <a href="javascript:closeCompareView();"> 
    <img    src="/images/quick-view-close-icon.png" id="close-it-img" />
    <div id="close-it-text">Close</div>
</a> 
</span>
<!-- close button -->

</div>
<div id="compare-top-bar">
    <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:window.print();"><div id="compare-print">Print</div></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);"><div id="compare-pdf">Create a PDF</div></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:loadEmailPage();"><div id="compare-email">Email</div></a></td>
            <td><div id="compare-social">
        <div style="margin-top: 1px; float: left; margin-right: 5px;">Social</div>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" target="_blank"> 
                <img src="/products/images/tweetn.png" /> 
            </a> 
            <a href="javascript:window.location=%22http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+%22&#38;t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" title="Share on Facebook..." target="_blank">
                <img src="/products/images/facebookn.png" /> 
            </a>
    </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<div id="compare-content" style="float: left">

<div id="cvcontainer" >
<form name = "compareForm" id = "compareForm" action="../shop/quickview/compareMail.jsp">
<input type="hidden" id="emailContent" value="${emailContent}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="cvids" value=""/>
<input type="hidden"name="axn" value="emailForm"/>
<div id="header"></div>



<div id="compare-holder" style="background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #24507D 0%, #143867 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; margin-top: 10px; padding: 10px 3px 10px 4px;">
<if !items>Nothing to compare <else><assign
    itemnum=0> 

    <foreach it in items>
<div id="cv_${it.item.id}" class="compare-slate" style="float: left"><a
    href="javascript:removeCompareViewItem(${it.item.id});">
<div id="removeBtnDiv" class="compare-remove">Remove</div>
</a>

<div class="compare-image"><img id="cv_img_${itemnum}"
    src="${cdnUrl}/cache/rh/${it.item.productImage}" /></div>

<div class="compare-gray-box">
<div class="compare-label">Suggested Price</div>
<if it.item.itemPrice>$${it.item.itemPrice}<else>&nbsp;</if>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="compare-white-box">
<div class="compare-label"><if it.item.sizeLabel>${it.item.sizeLabel}<else> </if></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="compare-gray-box-info">
<div class="compare-label">Description</div>
<a href="/my-servlets/CatalogSearch?id=${it.item.id}&amp;prodimage=${it.item.productImage}&amp;top=Y" class="compare-item-label">${it.item.name}</a>
<br />
<br />
${it.item.description}
</div>

<div class="compare-gray-box">
<div class="compare-label">Companion Availability</div>
Yes
</div>

<div class="compare-color-box">
<div class="compare-label">Colors</div>
<!--Use code from Quick View -->
<div style="float: left; paddig: 8px; margin-top: 10px; width: 100%;">
<!--sw--><assign knt=0> <foreach kolor in it.itemkolors><assign
    knt=knt+1> <if ((kolor.discontinued==
    "1") || (kolor.discontinued== "3")) && ((found==
    "N") || !swatchcolor || (kolor.colorName !=swatchcolor)||discontinued||closeout)>
<div id="cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}" class="swatch-names">${kolor.swatchColor} <!--<div id="s1_${knt}_arrow" class="swatch-arrow"></div>-->
</div>
<div
    onmousemove=" 
        document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.display='inline-table';
document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.left=mouseX+'px';
document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.top=mouseY+'px';"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.display='none';">
<a
    href="javascript:updateImgSrc('${cdnUrl}','${kolor.productImage}','cv_img_${itemnum}');"
    style="background-image: url(${cdnUrl}/cache/swatchgifs/${kolor.colorGif});">
<div id="d1_${knt}" class="kolor_swatch" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; float: left; margin: 0 5px 5px 0; background-image: url(/swatch/gifs/${kolor.colorGif}); border: #ccc solid 1px;">
<img src="/swatch/gifs/${kolor.colorGif}" alt="${kolor.swatchColor}" width="20px"
    height="20px" border="2"></div>
</a></div>
</if> </foreach> <assign first="Y"> <foreach kolor in itemkolors><assign
    knt=knt+1> <if (kolor.discontinued==
    "2" || kolor.discontinued== "3") && ((found==
    "N") || !swatchcolor || (kolor.colorName !=swatchcolor)||!discontinued)>
<if first=="Y"><assign first="N"> <br class="clearfloat">
<span style="float: left">Discontinued</span><br>
</if>
<div id="cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}" class="swatch-names">${kolor.swatchColor} <!--<div id="s1_${knt}_arrow" class="swatch-arrow"></div>-->
</div>
<div
    onmousemove=" 
        document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.display='inline-table';
document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.left=mouseX+'px';
document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.top=mouseY+'px';"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.display='none';">
<a
    href="javascript:updateImgSrc('${cdnUrl}','${kolor.productImage}','cv_img_${itemnum}');"
    style="background-image: url(${cdnUrl}/cache/swatchgifs/${kolor.colorGif})">
<div class="kolor_swatch" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; float: left; margin: 0 5px 5px 0; background-image: url(/swatch/gifs/${kolor.colorGif});">
<img src="/swatch/gifs/${kolor.colorGif}" width="20px" height="20px"></div>
</a></div>
</if> </foreach> <assign first="Y"> <foreach kolor in itemkolors><assign
    knt=knt+1> <if (kolor.discontinued== "9") && ((found==
    "N") || !swatchcolor || (kolor.colorName !=swatchcolor)||!discontinued)>
<if first=="Y"><assign first="N"> <br class="clearfloat">
<span style="float: left">Closeouts</span><br>
</if>
<div id="cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}" class="swatch-names">${kolor.swatchColor} <!--<div id="s1_${knt}_arrow" class="swatch-arrow"></div>-->
</div>
<div
    onmousemove="document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.display='inline-table';
        document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.left=mouseX+'px';
    document.getElementById('cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.top=mouseY+'px';"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById( 'cv_${it.item.id}_s1_${knt}').style.display='none'";
>
<a
    href="javascript:updateImgSrc('${cdnUrl}','${kolor.productImage}','cv_img_${itemnum}');"
    style="background-image: url(${cdnUrl}/cache/swatchgifs/${kolor.colorGif})">
<div  class="kolor_swatch" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; float: left; margin: 0 5px 5px 0; background-image: url(/swatch/gifs/${kolor.colorGif});">
<img src="/swatch/gifs/${kolor.colorGif}" width="20px" height="20px"></div>
</a></div>
</if> </foreach> <!--end sw--></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!--compare slate--> <assign itemnum=itemnum+1> </foreach> </if>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--compare holder--> <!--End my content-->

<div class="footer-gap"></div>
</form>

</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The AJAX call does not show popup and give following error:

> SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error

on following line:

```
window.document.getElementById('compareview-container').innerHTML=div.innerHTML;
```

I tried `jQuery('#compareview-container').html(results)`

The page refreshes and:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'extend' 
>   jquery.min.js, line 2 character 11496

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('compareview-container').innerHTML=""+result;

document.getElementById('compareview-container').innerHTML=result;
```

> SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your "data"

```
var params = "cvids=" + itemIds + "&ims=" + imgs
data:params,
type:'POST',
```

This makes no sense to me as a POST is sending data internally and not through the URL...
Try this:

```
var params = {"cvids":itemIds, "ims"=imgs}
```

and keep everything else the same

Comment: I have tried this but no luck (besides that is working fine over FF and chrome)